# DevExpress RepositoryItemComboBox cannot show combobox list data

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm using `gridControl.DataSource` from WCF Service and add manual `RepositoryItemComboBox` to `gridControl`. but `RepositoryItemComboBox` cannot show combo-box list data.

this my code :

```
gridControl8.DataSource = service.jadwalUmumStaff(data).Select(r => new
{
    hari = r.jadwal_umum.hari,
    shift = r.jadwal_umum.fk_jadwalUmum_Shift.id_shift,
    waktu = r.jadwal_umum.fk_jadwalUmum_Shift.waktu,
    mata_kuliah = r.jadwal_umum.fk_jadwalUmum_matakuliah.mata_kuliah,
    nama = r.staff.nama,
} ).ToList();

RepositoryItemComboBox nama = new RepositoryItemComboBox()
{
    TextEditStyle = TextEditStyles.DisableTextEditor,
    ShowDropDown = ShowDropDown.SingleClick
};

var a = service.getStaffID();
string[] _a = new string[a.Count()];
for (int i = 0; i < a.Count(); i++)
{
    _a[i] = a[i].id_staff;
}

nama.Items.AddRange(_a);
gridControl8.RepositoryItems.Add(nama);
gridView8.Columns[4].ColumnEdit = nama;
gridControl8.ForceInitialize();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need `AllowDropDownWhenReadOnly` and set value `true`

following this code :

```
RepositoryItemComboBox nama = new RepositoryItemComboBox()
{
    TextEditStyle = TextEditStyles.DisableTextEditor,
    AllowDropDownWhenReadOnly = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True
};
```